# How to add a timer in an animation.FuncAnimation (), using pandas/Geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, animation, timer, geopandas

I am creating an animation by using GeoPandas and everything is going well but I'd like to include a timer, in order to know the time corresponding to my visualization.

I think the way is by means of set_text, but I think everything is lost in the update done by Geopandas to plot (ax=ax).

So, the instruction time_text is the one that is not working on my code. Please any help/suggestion/idea? Thanks in advance!!

Here the important part of my code:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation

import geopandas as gpd

import pandas as pd

from shapely.geometry import Point


fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(2.5, 7), ylim=(48, 52))

time_text = ax.text(2.8, 50.,"",transform = ax.transAxes, ha="right")

ax.legend()

t=0

bel = gpd.read_file('....')

def init(): 

    global inicio

    inicio = bel.plot( ax=ax, color='black', markersize=5)

    time_text.set_text("")

    return inicio, time_text


data = pd.read_csv('.....')


legend = plt.legend(loc='lower left',prop={'size': 7})

def animate(i):

  global inu, iterar, t

  t += 1

  ax.clear()

  inu = bel.plot( ax=ax, color='lightgray', linewidth=1., edgecolor='black')

  cond = geo_data[ geo_data['newdate'].dt.minute == i]

  iterar = cond.plot(ax=ax,marker='s',color='yellow', markersize=7.,alpha=0.3,label='Max >= 60 Tonne');

  legend = plt.legend(loc='lower left',prop={'size': 7})

  time_text.set_text("time = "+str(t))

  return iterar,inu,time_text

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=60, interval=500, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format your code. You can highlight and hit ctrl+k to format it. Check out [help on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)